# calculate time difference and display popup based on time difference

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

im writing a small calendar based on php and jquery which has the a function to calculate the time difference and display a popup 15 minutes before.

Can some one tell me how can i calculate the time difference in minutes and popup 15 minutes before.

my time is saved as

```
18-07-2012 15:13:54
```

Comment: *"and display a popup 15 minutes before"* Before what?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, I think it's an alarm before 15 minutes of some calender entry. I believe the question is, in which language you want to do that? Javascript?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  as adnan mentioned its a alarm for the calender event. 15 minutes before the entry i would like to show the diary title as a popup..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uduqal/4/edit)*

```
var php = '19-07-2012 03:00:00'.split('-');
var phpDate   = php[1]+'/'+php[0]+'/'+php[2];
var phpTime   = new Date(phpDate).getTime();
var currTime  = new Date().getTime();
var difference= phpTime-currTime; 
var leftMin   = Math.ceil( difference/(1000*60) );

$('#test').text(leftMin+' MINUTES LEFT!');
```

---

**Code explanation:**

To get the remaining time I've done a millisecond comparison of the `php` returned time in milliseconds from Jan. 1 1970
 and the current time in `ms`  from Jan 1 1970 - subtracting the two values and getting the milliseconds difference. To calculate that difference in **minutes** I've just done:

```
 var leftMin   = Math.ceil( difference/(1000*60) );
```

The trick was to get the right time format and to revert your (php) returned time to that format too.
The default format looks like: `MONTH/DAY/YEAR HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS`

To convert the php returned time `'19-07-2012 03:00:00'`to that one, I used:

```
var php = '19-07-2012 03:00:00'.split('-');   // split in array fractions
var phpDate   = php[1]+'/'+php[0]+'/'+php[2]; // reposition array keys and add '/'
```

which returns: `07/19/2012 03:00:00` and now we can compare it to the current time e.g.:

```
           07/19/2012 03:45:21
```

To retrieve the `ms` from your converted php time we can use:

```
var phpTime   = new Date(phpDate).getTime();  // get "ms from our string
```

and for the current time we just take:

```
var currTime  = new Date().getTime();         // get "ms from 1/1/1970
```

Now having our two milliseconds values we can simply subtract them to get the remaining time:

```
var difference= phpTime-currTime;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code explanation. made a few changes to suit my program and works perfectly :)

Comment: @LiveEn :) nice, glad you did it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check PHP's [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)! Maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

php has an mktime() function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) which takes in a hours, minutes, seconds, month, day, year and calculates the seconds since the epoch (in like 1971).  Then you can subtract 15*60 use the date() function to go from seconds back to a date format. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateStr = '18-07-2012 15:13:54'//Day-Month-Year
var dateArray = dateStr.split('-')
var d1 = new Date(dateArray[1]+'-'+dateArray[0]+'-'+dateArray[2])

var dateStr2 = '18-07-2012 14:10:54'//Day-Month-Year
var dateArray2 = dateStr2.split('-')
var d2 = new Date(dateArray2[1]+'-'+dateArray2[0]+'-'+dateArray2[2])

var minutes = (d1-d2)/1000/60
```

-edit; revised code below:-

```
function timeDiff(date1, date2){
//date format: Day-Month-Year
var dateArray = date1.split('-')
var d1 = new Date(dateArray[1]+'-'+dateArray[0]+'-'+dateArray[2])

var dateArray2 = date2.split('-')
var d2 = new Date(dateArray2[1]+'-'+dateArray2[0]+'-'+dateArray2[2])

var minutes = (d1-d2)/1000/60
return minutes;
}

if(timeDiff('18-07-2012 15:13:54', '18-07-2012 14:59:54')<=15){
alert('popup')
}
```